# Detecting users emotions by analyzing the text

Tags: data-mining, text-mining

im doing a project which will detect users emotions through text? Im new to this area im still finding the best algorithm to detect the emotions from text.suggest me a good method to do this?

Comment: You might also submit this question here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod I don't think this question will be welcome on [Programmers.SE] in it's current form. It shows no prior reseach, and is asking for "the best", which can be subjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use in a simple way:

1. Build a list of lets say 300 quotes with respective emotion.

> I'm done of this kind of game   => Bored
>  
>   Size doesn't mean everything    => Defense
>   I will bring you all pain       => Angry
>   Fortune doesn't favor fools     => advise

2. Now make a filter to select only important words from each phrase, removing words that will not impact in the meaning
3. Create a range from 0 to 100 and lets create for example 5 emotions that will fit 0-20 21-40 41-60 61-80 81-100. Each emotion will be filled in a range. For example a good range would be:
   `coolness -> happiness -> normal -> bored -> sad`
4. Now for each important word from step 2 you will have to assign a number in the range of 0-100 that most describe the emotion (For example: very happy is 1 little happy is 20 little sad is 81 very sad is 100)
5. now you will have quotes like numbers and you can put emotions in array of numbers
6. Now you can use a Neural Network (you will train the NN with your arrays and for a new entry it will try to 'say' what is the emotion that is seems to be.

Lets suppose you find a tool for training and testing NN as below.

[image: nn image]

Each of the inputs will be the numbers of your "emotion array" and the output will be a binary number. if you want represent a 0-4 (cool to sad) range, so you will need 3 outputs (3 bits = 8 possible numbers represented since 2 bit we can only 4 numbers)

the training file for your neural network will look like below:

> i1 i2 i3 i4 output
>   21 27 01 07 1
>   01 07 02 91 5
>   15 27 31 40 3
>   16 01 07 55 4

By words it means: for this set of inputs representing these emotions i will have to show 1 (happy) and the same thinking to the other lines

THis file will be lots of lines of traning (300 i said above) and the result of the training will be the WEIGHTS of the neural networks be calibrated to your "artificial inteligence"

Of course the output depends of the quality of your data and your filter.

Also you will have to study how many inputs your Neural network will have, how many layers and so on.

Comment: thankz will try your method..

Comment: thankz for ur answer...can u type ur email address here..or can u send a mail to nishihettiarachchi@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

If have to do this I will divide it into 2 step process:

1. Make/Create a list/DB of emotion expressions/words ( like Happy, angry, bad or sad) from dictionaries. I am not sure but there might be already some API's from dictionaries Other wise you can maintain by your self. 
   For example :
   http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/sad
   http://www.psychpage.com/learning/library/assess/feelings.html
2. Check if the Users's text contains these Sad/Bad words.

You can create a user's text profile by capturing of any such word's count in the text. At the end based on these counts you can predict.

Comment: i thought of doing it like that but the problem is there are lots of words for any given emotion.Im searching for a method like which could split the sentence in to separate parts and check their special words.Something like that

Comment: I though the problem is to define a word if it is special (indicates some emotion). There might be cost in this but it should be thread safe to run in parallel. So my one process will break the statement word by word and n threads will check if these words have some emotional indication.  Diving a statement into sub parts should be easy. Do you see some problem?